# How to pass form parameters to Rest using angularjs services?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

I try to pass my form parameters to java rest backend but i cant.

controller

```
$scope.addNewThing = function () {
    Myservice.addNew($scope.name);
};
```

service

```
addNew: function (name) {
     var Foo = $resource($rootScope.baseUrl + '/path/addNew', {}, {
          save: {method: 'POST', params: {}}
     });

     var results = Foo.save({name: name}, function(data) {
          results = data;
     });

     return results;
}

//also tried this version of code

addNew: function(name) {

     return $resource($rootScope.baseUrl + '/path/addNew', {}, {
         save: {method: 'POST', params: {name: 'test'}}
     });
}
```

rest backend function

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/addNew")
public Response addNew(@FormParam("name") String name) {
    try {
         //when i check name here it is always null
         ...
    }
}
```

I can't pass the html form parameter to java rest backend via angular. Also tried to change `@FormParam` to `@QueryParam` but it didn't work.

Comment: use `data` instead of `params` inside your http request

Comment: is this a wrong way using $resource and params for post request? @messerbill

Comment: no sorry, its not. this was my fault...wait a moment

Comment: any errors in the browser console? how does the HTTP response look like?

Comment: there were no errors, it calls properly my backend function but not passing the parameters.

Comment: and how does the http response look like? you can see it in your Chrome Inspection tool / Firebug

Comment: there is nothing on chrome console, backend function returns nothing cause i just check for parameter is null or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109832/discussion-between-messerbill-and-cgrgcn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery params solved my problem

Here is the correct way:

```
    Myservice.addNew().save($.param({
        name:$scope.name
    }),function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },function(err){
         console.log(err);
    });
```

I can pass the parameters like this with $resource service.

Answer (score 0):

I don'n know how to receive `params` value in `java` but I can show how to pass `params` from angular `service`. when you will want to pass params then you should use `:paramsName` in your URL path.

```
addNew: function(name) {
   var addNewItem = $resource($rootScope.baseUrl + '/path/addNew/:name', {name: '@name'}, {
       'post': {method: 'GET'}
   });
   return addNewItem.post({name: name});
}
```

**or** if you don't use `/:name` in your url you should pass in your header

```
addNew: function(name) {
    var addNewItem = $resource($rootScope.baseUrl + '/path/addNew/:name', {}, {
       'post': {method: 'GET', headers: { 'name': name }}
     });
     return addNewItem.post({name: name});
}
```

NB: your `Content-Type` should be `application/json`

Comment: is this the right way if service url doesnt waiting for parameters like /path/addNew/{name} ?

Comment: then you should pass `params` value in `header`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the default `content-type` on `$http` POST requests?

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
});
```

Comment: i have this one `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';` i am trying yours now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.addNewThing = function () {
    yourService.addNew($scope.name);
};
```

SERVICE

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .service('yourService',['$http', function ($http) {

  this.addNew = function (data) {

    $http({
          url: 'YourURL',
          method: 'POST',
          data: data, // your $scope.name
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
      })
      .success(function (response) {
        console.log('good');
      })
      .error(function (response) {
        console.log('error');
      });

  };
}]);
```

JAVA REST API

```
@POST
@Path("/addNew")
@Consumes("*/*")
public Response addNew(String name) {
   // use here your String name
}
```